# How to import @VisibleForTesting

Tags: spring, testing, mockito, guava

I know that exists the annotation `@VisibleForTesting`. I want to use it, but I don't understand how to import it.
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the Guava annotation `com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635796/how-to-autowire-object-to-bean-if-class-does-not-have-setter/18636203?noredirect=1#18636203  from one of answers

Answer (score 4):

The annotation is available in the 'guava' library, so with maven you can use this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve this by building the whole android source code, and then add the `class.jar` file under
`out\target\common\obj\JAVA_LIBRARIES\guava_intermediates` as a user library into eclipse
[image]

and import it into my java file.
The IDE doesn't indicate any error

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your imports

```
import com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting;
```

Comment: Incomplete answer - also need to have the library on the classpath.